# Create a matrix which contains 1 column of all the objects in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

If we have this list with 100 objects:

```
List
[[1]]
  x       y      z 
 379.0    0.6    1.0 
 369.0    0.3    2.0

[[2]]
  x       y      z 
 359.0    6.2    4.0 
 379.0    4.6    1.0

[[3]]
  x       y      z 
 379.0    6.0    1.0 
 379.0    0.5    1.0
.
.
[[100]]
```

How could I obtain a matrix using "y" values of list-columns of each object (all of them have the same length), obtaining something like:

```
X:
y1     y2     y3        ...       y100
0.6    6.2    6.0 
0.3    4.6    0.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below:

```
# example list
l <- list(cars[1:3, ], cars[4:6, ])
l
# [[1]]
#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 
# [[2]]
#   speed dist
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10
```

Subset 2nd column using *"["* function, then bind columns:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(l, "[", 2))
#   dist dist
# 1    2   22
# 2   10   16
# 3    4   10
```

Or another similar approach, instead of binding columns, we convert to *data.frame*:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(l, "[", 2))
#   dist dist.1
# 1    2     22
# 2   10     16
# 3    4     10
```

**Note:** We could subset using column names, too. In my example data 2nd column name is *"dist"*, so replace number *2* above with *"dist"* and it should work the same.

Comment: Nice but wouldn't `do.call(cbind, lapply(l, "[", "dist"))` be less fragile?

Comment: @snoram of course, we could address using column index or using column name. I didn't want to introduce "dist" as it is an example data. Clarified the post with a note.

Comment: Or with `tidyverse` `map(l, '[', 2) %>% bind_cols`